# Creating a list in a Dataframe column which is a range of values from other two data frame columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to create a list in a dataframe column, which is a range of numbers. The range limits should be the values in other two data frame columns.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [3, 7, 2, 8], 'B': [1, 3, 9, 3]},index=[1,2,3,4])
```

Now In need a dataframe column which will be series of lists like below

```
[1,2,3]
[3,4,5,6,7]
[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
[3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

I'm able to create a list in a dataframe column this way.

```
df['C'] = (df[['A','B']]).to_numpy().tolist()
```

This gives a column as below

```
[3,1]
[7,3]
[2,9]
[8,3]
```

But I'm not able to figure out how to create a list that is range of these values in a dataframe column.

I have also defined a fuction which will generate a list of range of numbers for any given two numbers

```
def createlist(r1,r2):
    if (r1 == r2):
        return r1
    elif (r1 < r2):
        res = []
  
        while(r1 < r2+1 ):              
            res.append(r1)
            r1 += 1
        return res    
    else:
        res = []
  
        while(r1+1 > r2 ):
              
            res.append(r2)
            r2 += 1
        return res
```

But struggling to apply this function to generate a dataframe column while taking inputs from other columns. Can you please help out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't there a little mistake in your desired output? the 3rd row should be a list in range 2 to 9 if I understand it right (instead of `[2,3]`)

Answer (score 3):

You can try `DataFrame.apply` on rows

```py
df['C'] = df.apply(lambda row: list(range(row.min(), row.max()+1)), axis=1)
```

```
print(df)

   A  B                         C
1  3  1                 [1, 2, 3]
2  7  3           [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
3  2  9  [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
4  8  3        [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This works :) Just and additional query. I'm going to do this for a very large dataset with multiple rows and columns. So picking the minimum and maximum will also include the other column values. How can we generate this output only using the values of these two columns? Just a curious question and it will be of great help, if you could answer.

Comment: @karthikselva You can use `row[['A','B']]`.